# Create stored procedure to select the data?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures

I have four tables user, shops, offer, merchant in that id is unique and present in all table

```
shop
------
id  shops
1    shop1
1    shop2
1    shop3
```

```
user
-----
id   name
1    abc
```

```
merchant
---------
id   date      business
1   2012-6-6    Mall
```

```
offer
------
id   status
1    true
1    true
1    false
```

First select id from shop table then match with user to get username, then match with merchant table to get date, business.

Then match with shop table to get shops (count the shops that how much that id have), then match with offer table to get status (count the status=true that how much that id have)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: So firstly, you must create parent-child relationships between your tables. I suspect that a merchant may have one or more shops and more than one offer per shop. So, you may wish to start with merchant and create a column of shop ids in the merchant table. Then, create a one-to-many relationship between shops, offers, and users. Your example can be improved further; however, we need to start somewhere, no?

Comment: Please clarify your final objective. Type a sample result for example.

Comment: name   shops   offer   business   date                                                    ----------------------------------------                         abc    3        2       mall     2012-6-6

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't the "write code for you because you are too lazy to try" site.